# In Hugo documentation, what is meant by `⊢--^-⊣` and similar?

Tags: hugo

In the Hugo documentation, I sometimes see code blocks that look like this:

[Organization docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/organization/)

> You can keep one _index.md for your homepage and one in each of your
>   content sections, taxonomies, and taxonomy terms. The following shows
>   typical placement of an _index.md that would contain content and front
>   matter for a posts section list page on a Hugo website:

```
.         url
.       ⊢--^-⊣
.        path    slug
.       ⊢--^-⊣⊢---^---⊣
.           filepath
.       ⊢------^------⊣
content/posts/_index.md
```

What is being said, here? Is "the following" referring to a directory structure? Is that what a file (which file?) would actually look like? Is the `url` and `path` etc words some sort of variables, that are being "pointed to" by the `|---^--|`? Or is the dash caret syntax actual code, and `⊢--^-⊣` means "URL" in human-readable terms?

**What does the `-`, `|`, `^`, `||` syntax mean in the Hugo docs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using the dash caret syntax as a attempt to explain(not clearly) the directory structure.

```
url = /posts/
slug = _index.md
filepath = /posts/_index.md
```

The `-`, `|`, `^`, `||` are strictly used to illustrate the url structure and nothing more

Comment: I sense you are correct, however, even with your elucidation, the content is totally incomprehensible to me... I genuinely cannot understand what I am looking at here.

Comment: OH, so, hold on, both the URL and the PATH are "/posts/"?

Comment: yes, they have two names for it. They also refer to it as ''section" 'which would not include the forward slashes 'posts'